# Process.start não abre a osk.exe em C#

Tags: c#

Estou a usar a `Process.start()` para abrir algumas aplicações do sistema, contudo apesar de funcionar corretamente para o `notepad` e para a calculadora, quando tento abrir o teclado de ecrã (`osk.exe`) o programa tem uma finalização abrupta e dá o seguinte erro:

> "The system cannot find the file especified"

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
private void calculadoraToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("calc.exe");
}

private void blocoDeNotasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
}

private void tecladoNoEcrãToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("osk.exe");
}
```

Comment: Abra um prompt do PowerShell e digite `[diagnostics.process]::Start("osk.exe")`. Qual o resultado?

Comment: no PowerShell funciona... curioso pq dentro do C#, mesmo colocando `FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");` mostra que o arquivo não existe. Deve ser uma questão de segurança

Comment: @AugustoVasques se eu tentar executar esse código na PowerShell a aplicação é executada, contudo, em C# esta não tem o mesmo efeito.

Comment: De dentro do prompt do c# interativo(`csi.exe`) eu consegui chamar o `osk.exe`. Usei as linhas: `> using System.Diagnostics;` e `> Process.Start("osk.exe");`. Vou abrir uma instância do Visual Studio.

Comment: Aqui funciona de boas

Comment: @LeandroAngelo executas-te isso no visual studio ou na PowerShell?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo No visual studio não funciona. [Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbehj.png) , [conversão do hresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwEyf.png) , [tabela de erros do OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4t3v.png)

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, Achei o problema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo porque o processo `osk.exe` é um processo de 64-bits.

Por padrão uma aplicação do *Visual Studio* é compilada para plataformas de 32 bits para garantir uma maior compatibilidade, o problema é que esse tipo de aplicativo só consegue inicializar processos também de 32 bits.

Para resolver o problema é preciso compilar uma aplicação de 64 bits.

- Abra as propriedades do seu projeto:

[image: propriedades do projeto]

- Na aba **Build** em **Platform Target:** selecione **x64**

[image: Selecionar plataforma]

- Só compilar e executar:

[image: Código funcionando]

Comment: Isso mesmo, eu ia até comentar que eu tinha rodado no C# Interactive (64 bits)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo no CSI e Powershell ele funciona tranquilo. O problema é específico plataforma x86 do VS cujo o assemblie `System.Diagnostics` ligado no código não consegue abrir uma aplicação de 64 bits.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: @DuochannelYT, Precisa agradecer não, foi divertido caçar o problema.